# Find array length in zsh script

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, bash-array

Is there a way to find the length of the array `*`(files names) in zsh without using a for loop to increment some variable?

I naively tried `echo ${#*[@]}`  but it didn't work. (bash syntax are welcome as well)

Comment: By "length of the array" do you mean its number of elements? And do you want to get this without actually defining this array (`*` suggest you want to use shell globing mechanism here)?

Comment: Oops, you're right i should have asked the other way around, I'll edit it.

Comment: @Cristiano: zsh doesn't have anything to do with it.  `*` is not an array in the way you are using it, it is a shell glob.  Arrays have nothing to do with your question unless you create an array as Jeff did in his answer.  Your question is "How do I find how many files are in the current directory"

Comment: @Jess_b But it acts like an array don't you think? `echo *[0]` in zsh prints the 1st file name...

Comment: @Cristiano: I believe that is a zsh specific glob qualifier but still doesn't make the glob an array

Comment: re-edit your question and answer @jimmij 's question then your question will be reviewed again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`${#*[@]}` would be the length of the `$*` array also known as `$@` or `$argv`, which is the array of positional parameters (in the case of a script or function, that's the arguments the script or function received). Though you'd rather use `$#` for that.

`*` alone is just a glob pattern. In list context, that's expanded to the list of files in the current directory that match that pattern. As `*` is a pattern that matches any string, it would expand to all file names in the current directory (except for the *hidden* ones).

Now you need to find a *list context* for that `*` to be expanded, and then somehow count the number of resulting arguments. One way could be to use an anonymous function:

```
() {echo There are $# non hidden files in the current directory} *(N)
```

Instead of `*`, I used `*(N)` which is `*` but with the `N` (for nullglob) globbing qualifier which makes it so that if the `*` pattern doesn't match any file, instead of reporting an error, it expands to nothing at all.

The expansion of `*(N)` is then passed to that anonymous function. Within that anonymous function, that list of file is available in the `$@`/`$argv` array, and we get the length of that array with `$#` (same as `$#argv`, `$#@`, `$#*` or even the awkward ksh syntax like `${#argv[@]}`).

Comment: Would you actually call `$*` an array at all? A "string" would be a better word for it, IMHO. Maybe it's different in `zsh`?

Comment: @Kusalananda how could it be a string if the elements it's made of are words/strings themselves? When `$*` is used inside double quotes, the words it's made of (`$1`, `$2`, ...) will be joined by the first char of `IFS` without its elements being split on `IFS` or spaces before that: `(set -- 'a/b' 'a  b'; IFS=:/; echo "<$*>")` (this latter digression is to illustrate that `$*` is not somehow a string split an then rejoined in this particular syntax).

Comment: @mosvy I know he mentions `$*` and `$@` unquoted, but `"$*"` is at least _clearly_ a string whereas `"$@"` is not a single string. Calling `$*` an array and saying another name for it is `$@` seems to confuse the purpose of these two variables.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it's the array of positional parameters. `zsh` and `yash` have real arrays and arrays whose indice start at 1, so they can represent that array as a normal array variable. That array goes by the `*`, `@` and `argv` names in `zsh`. Except that `$@` is special inside double quotes on list contexts like it was in the Bourne shell. `$*` inside double quotes expands to the concatenation of the elements like `$argv` or `$argv[*]` (or even `$*[*]`) do, but that doesn't make it less that `$argv` is an array variable, not a scalar variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
files=(*)
printf 'There are %d files\n' "${#files[@]}"
```

or

```
set -- *
printf 'There are %d files\n' "$#"
```

You have to name the array first (as I did above with `files`) or use the built-in array `$@` by populating it with the wildcard, as I did in the second example. In the former, the "length" (number of files) of the array is done with the `${#arrayname[@]}` syntax. The number of elements in the built-in array is in `$#`.

Comment: So the  `* ` acts as a regex expression? I thought that it was a special array... although surprise me that there is no such array...

Comment: wait, in zsh  `*[0] or *[1] ` gives me some file name... now I'm puzzled.

Comment: The array is $@... $* equals a single string with each argument separated by $IFS (usually space). ZSH and Bash doesn't handle usage of an "index" in space-delimited strings the same way.

Comment: Cristiano, the `*[0]` in zsh would expand to filenames that start with anything (or nothing) followed by any of the following characters: `0`.  The square brackets designates a set of characters in that position. You likely have files that end with a zero in your current directory.  To tell zsh to give you back the first element of a `*` wildcard, you'd use parenthesis for array syntax: `print -l *([1])` -- noting that zsh arrays start at 1 unless you set `$KSH_ARRAYS`